# android access final variable in a public sub

Tags: android, final, anonymous-inner-class

I have a checkbox in android UI interface that need to set confirm.
I need to declare it as final as it need to access it inside the inner class.
However, I also want a public sub to check the value of the checkbox and also reset it.

The problem is I cannot access the final variable `chkConfirm` inside public sub.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final CheckBox chkConfirm;
    chkConfirm = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkConfirm);
    chkConfirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chkConfirm.isChecked()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
    chkConfirm.setChecked(false);

    }

public Boolean isConfirmed() {
    if (chkConfirm.isChecked() ) {
        chkConfirm.setChecked(false);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

How to solve?

Comment: you want to use the variable like a property of class. Declare it as a variable of class, so that you can refer to it whenever you are working with this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `final CheckBox chkConfirm` to the class, as private variable:

```
private CheckBox chkConfirm;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    chkConfirm = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkConfirm);
    chkConfirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chkConfirm.isChecked()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
    chkConfirm.setChecked(false);

    }

public Boolean isConfirmed() {
    if (chkConfirm.isChecked() ) {
        chkConfirm.setChecked(false);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it work. Just need to remove the one inside onCreate.